# Find date after a particular word

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I would like to find the date in a string after a particular word (key).
My string is dynamic and the date format also not same from one string to another string.

```
$data = "Balance- 0.30,Val-Aug 29 2013, Free Bal- 0.00";
or
$data = "Bal: 96.27.Valid Sep 26 2013.Toll Free Dial 578785";
or
$data = "BalanceRs.0.00,Expiry date: Apr 04 20141 Live Scores";
or
$data = "Your current balance is 0.20.Your account expires on 2013-11-23 23:59:59.";
or
$data = "Main Bal Rs.87.850 Val 09-07-2014,More";


$key = array('Val-','Val','Valid','Expiry date:','expires on');

$result=preg_match_all("/(?<=(".$key."))(\s\w*)/i",$data,$networkID);
$myanswer = @$networkID[0][0];
```

Here I am getting the output of only the first word.

Anyone please guide me to get the date. Thanks.

Comment: $key should be a pipe separated string not an array

Comment: Yup. Or `implode('|', $key)`.

Comment: @Dagon and jason Thanks for your reply. If I am not wrong, I Hope we can use array. The code above is to find a word after a particular word. But now I would like to find the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$data = "Balance- 0.30,Val-Aug 29 2013, Free Bal- 0.00";
$data .= "Bal: 96.27.Valid Sep 26 2013.Toll Free Dial 578785";
$data .= "BalanceRs.0.00,Expiry date: Apr 04 20141 Live Scores";
$data .= "Your current balance is 0.20.Your account expires on 2013-11-23 23:59:59.";
$data .= "Main Bal Rs.87.850 Val 09-07-2014,More";

$key = array('Valid','Val-','Val','Expiry date:','expires on');
$key_str = implode('|', $key);
preg_match_all("/(?<=$key_str)\s*((?:\w{3} \d\d \d{4})|(?:\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d)|(?:\d\d-\d\d-\d{4}))/i", $data, $networkID);
print_r($networkID);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Aug 29 2013
            [1] =>  Sep 26 2013
            [2] =>  Apr 04 2014
            [3] =>  2013-11-23
            [4] =>  09-07-2014
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Aug 29 2013
            [1] => Sep 26 2013
            [2] => Apr 04 2014
            [3] => 2013-11-23
            [4] => 09-07-2014
        )

)
```

Comment: awsome, thanks for your help. I want to get all the result in the same format as d/m/y is there any option to convert all the date in the same format.